# Como fazer a correlação entre todas as variaveis de um dataset ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: r

Tenho esse dataset com notas de alunos em cada matéria:

```
BIOLOGIA | FILOSOFIA | FÍSICA |GEOGRAFIA |HISTÓRIA |LÍNGUA INGLESA|
   21        NA         21        25       20             25
   18        15         16        16       16             18
   15        25         15        20       25             16
   17        17         15        17       17             24
```

E preciso fazer a correlação entre todas as materias:
BIOLOGIA x FILOSOFIA
BIOLOGIA x GEOGRAFIA
FILOSOFIAx GEOGRAFIA

Usando a funçao cor, eu consigo correlacionar par por par de materia.

`temp <- WGCNA::cor((FILOSOFIA,GEOGRAFIA)[1,1])`

Mas queria saber se tem uma forma de gerar o resultado de todos os pares de uma unica vez, usando R.
Existe uma forma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é necessário usar a função `WGCNA::cor`, a não ser que os conjuntos de dados sejam muito grandes e cálculos rápidos sejam necessários. Em geral, a função `cor` já resolve a maioria dos problemas que envolvem cálculos de correlação no R.

Sendo assim, basta ter um data frame composto de apenas colunas com dados numéricos e aplicar a função `cor` do R base diretamente nele:

```r
iris2 <- iris[, -5]
cor(iris2)
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000  -0.1175698    0.8717538   0.8179411
#> Sepal.Width    -0.1175698   1.0000000   -0.4284401  -0.3661259
#> Petal.Length    0.8717538  -0.4284401    1.0000000   0.9628654
#> Petal.Width     0.8179411  -0.3661259    0.9628654   1.0000000
```

Inclusive, é possível calcular correlações diferentes da correlação de Pearson com essa função. Abaixo mostro como calcular as correlações de Spearman para todas as colunas do conjunto de dados:

```r
cor(iris2, method = "spearman")
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000  -0.1667777    0.8818981   0.8342888
#> Sepal.Width    -0.1667777   1.0000000   -0.3096351  -0.2890317
#> Petal.Length    0.8818981  -0.3096351    1.0000000   0.9376668
#> Petal.Width     0.8342888  -0.2890317    0.9376668   1.0000000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Obrigada Marcus!!

Tem um ponto, que eu acho interressante colocar. Se alguma variavel tiver NA como valor, a correlação com ela sai no valor de NA.

Comment: Sim, exatamente! Uma maneira de evitar isso é utilizando o argumento `use = complete.obs`, da seguinte maneira: `cor(iris2, use = "complete.obs")`.